# Why do they sometimes not use a real operating system in films?

Tags: props

Why is it that sometimes TV shows and movies use real operating systems (ie: Windows, Mac OS or Linux) and computers but then sometimes hide the logos or use a fake OS with an unrealistic GUI?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> It could be for dramatization, or it may be caused by legal and/or
>   financial issues. Some of the reasons are listed:
>
> - OSs and software interfaces are considered intellectual property, and are therefore copyright protected. Most of them are or also represent
>     a brand. It would require a paid or unpaid agreement by the
>     copyright holder or brand owner to depict them.
>     In *24* (TV series) for instance, CTU has been using Apple Displays most of the time while the software shown was proprietary. Apple
>     remained uncredited. In later seasons however, *24* made heavy use of
>     "Cisco Teleconference Systems", and showed their logo frequently. The
>     credits revealed that there was financial support by Cisco
>     accordingly.
> - Product placement is still not legal in many countries without a "proper warning" (e.g. in Germany).
> - Most OSs or familiarly known software apps don't do as quickly and easily what a screenplay requires them to do. They also don't look as
>     spectacular and certainly not lucid enough to display the necessary
>     clarity and/or impressiveness for a quick cut to their interface in
>     order to reveal at a glimpse what the machine is currently chewing on.
> - There is an image problem. It has been a strong habit for the last decade to show the good guys using Apple Macs vs. the bad guys using
>     Windows PCs. It's
>     certainly not a problem that the bad guys use Windows, but it is a
>     problem if the good guys win, because the bad guys used Windows
>     (hacked their system or something fictional that wouldn't -- or
>     actually would! -- work in reality). If you look closely, you will
>     often find Apple computers with the logo rendered unrecognizable,
>     while the case design is obviously non-PC.
>     [(source)](http://www.quora.com/Why-do-movies-and-TV-shows-often-show-fake-operating-systems-and-software-interfaces)

And sometimes movies/TV shows don't show the real logo or operating system just to hide the real product because they are not getting paid for it. I mean the producer/director is not willing to do free advertisement.

> For more details on fake brand endorsing in movies and TV shows, refer
>   to the following questions:
>
> [1) Are fictional trademarks or brand names used in movies and TV
>   legally held?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2418/are-fictional-trademarks-or-brand-names-used-in-movies-and-tv-legally-held)
>
> [2) Why do so many movies & TV shows feature recognizable, un-branded
>   or re-branded products?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1665/why-do-so-many-movies-tv-shows-feature-recognizable-un-branded-or-re-branded)

May this answer help you in some way.

Comment: _[Apple won’t pay to have their products featured, but they are more than willing to hand out an endless amount of computers, iPads, and iPhones](http://www.businessinsider.com/apple-product-placements-in-tv-and-movies-2012-8?op=1)_

Comment: And there are clearly shows where a technology is prominently featured. For example "Hawaii Five-0" where Microsoft hardware and software products are very obvious. I believe there is also an explicit credit about this in the roll.